# how to enable CORS for XML data

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I am building a web application where I need to get XML data from several cross-domain feeds.

The annoying thing is: they're cross-domain. I currently use a jQuery (script) on the "local" domain, which fetches the XML from the other domain.

For enabling CORS I added headers and here is my code

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRateFromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR',
            type: 'post',
            crossDomain: true,
            ContentType: 'application/xml',
            Origin: 'http://www.webservicex.net',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow origin': 'http://www.webservicex.net',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                'Request Headers CAUTION': 'Provisional headers are shown',
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'accept, content-type',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST'

            })
```

but still I'm getting CORS problem while I was running in  Firefox

and the error I'm getting is

```
Accept  
*/*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    
true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    
http://www.webservicex.net
Cookie  
_ga=GA1.1.256593039.1431427019
Host    
localhost:8383
Referer 
http://localhost:8383/CordovaApp/index3.html
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and friends are **response** headers, not request headers. Your JavaScript can't give itself permission to access content across origins.

Comment: "and the error I'm getting is" —That isn't an error. It's a (badly formatted) by perfectly normal (aside from trying to set access control) request header.

Comment: `ContentType: 'application/xml',` — You haven't set `data` to anything. Since you aren't POSTing any data, why are you saying that the data you are posting is an XML document?

Comment: `Origin: 'http://www.webservicex.net',` — Why are you trying to set this explicitly? The browser adds the origin header automatically.

Comment: `crossDomain: true,` — why are you setting this? You said your script is returning data from other origins, not that it redirects to them.

Comment: I'm not getting any data, that is Why I'm setting crossDomain: true and it is not even hitting the service

Comment: What makes you think it isn't even hitting the service? Does the Net tab of your developer tools display a time out error?

Comment: yes, and while I was running in chrome it was showing me 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE        http://localahost:8383/CordovaApp/cordava.js

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE        http://localahost:8383/CordovaApp/favicon.ico


Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE        http://localahost:8383/CordovaApp/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR

Comment: And I 'm problem if it is calling http://localhost:8383/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR 

but I need to call 

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR 

could you help me out with this problem

Comment: In both cases it sounds like you just need to type the URLs you actually want. If you want an absolute URL then start it with `http://` and then specify the domain instead of making it relative to your current site. If you want `localhost` then type `localhost` and not `localahost` with an extra `a`.

Comment: In my scenario, I'm trying to us  http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR

for that I wrote ajax call as mention above but still it is going to my domain i,e, localhost:8383

http://localhost:8383/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR

so could you guide me like how to call www.webservicex.net domain instead of my domain ,i.e, localhost:8383

Comment: You change `url: '/CurrencyConve` to `url: 'http://webservicex.net//CurrencyConve`

Comment: Still I'm getting error as

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).


Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Comment: Then you need to get  webservicex.net to give your JavaScript permission to access the data (or use a proxy)

Comment: can explain how to access data in JavaScript using webservicex.net or how to set/use proxy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: can you explain briefly or else send some link as reference on how to  to access data in JavaScript using webservicex.net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy